# I want each individual return value from the reduce() function rather than the total

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```
      previousValue currentValue    index         array      return value
first call       0        1               1          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    1
second call      1        2               2          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    3
third call       3        3               3          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    6
fourth call      6        4               4          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    10
```

I want 1,3,6,10 in an array not the return total 10. So to return each call

Comment: Then adjust the function used in `.reduce()` to add the sum of `(previousValue + currentValue)` into an array.

Comment: Then, perhaps you should use `.map()` instead (since it will produce an output array for you) and just have a higher scoped variable to keep the running total.

Comment: I looked at the map function but doesn't it look at one element at a time-  you can pass(a,b) ?

Comment: Andreas what's an example of this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There are different ways to accomplish this task. One would be with `.reduce()` but this is not the only one. A simple `for` loop can also do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the return value into an array, like this. It goes against functional programming since it mutates `results` as a side effect. But it does meet your needs.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var results = [];

array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    var newValue = previousValue + currentValue;
    results.push(newValue);
    return newValue;
});

// result is 1,3,6,10
alert(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use reduce for this. Slice the array, shift a value to start a subtotal, then use map.

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], output = arr.slice(), subtotal = output.shift()
output = output.map(function(elem) { return subtotal += elem })
// output is [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Edit - Actually, this could work fine with reduce, and even more concise than the above:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.reduce(function(a, b, ndx) { return a.length ? a.concat(a[ndx - 2] + b) : [a + b]})
// returns [1, 3, 6, 10]
```